# transition between multiple images with ImageMagick with transitions

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am new to ImageMagick, and would naively like to find a command that I can run to create a slideshow from a number of jpeg images with the same fade transition between all images.

I have looked on a number of tutorials / forums, but have only been able to find examples of transitions between 2 images, not 3, 4, or 5 images etc.

I have 5 images (01.jspeg, 02.jpeg, 03.jpeg...etc) that I would like to turn into a slideshow. I would like the slideshow to have the same fade transition between each image. I tried the command line below but it is not behaving as expected!

```
convert  01.jpeg 02.jpeg 03.jpeg 04.jpeg 05.jpeg -loop 0 morph 9 -set delay "%[fx:(t>0&&t<n-1)?10:320]" output.gif
```

My presumption of the above code is that a gif would be created of a slideshow of the 5 images with a fade transition between each. but this is not the resulting behaviour.

I am an experienced developer but have no eperience of ImageMagick.

Could someone please let me know what I am misunderstanding about the way that ImageMagic works! Thanks!

I am assuming tha the morph argument provided is applied to all transitions... is this not correct?

Comment: If on a Unix-like system, Linux, Mac OSX, Windows 10 Unix, Windows w/ Cygwin, you can try my bash ImageMagick scripts, transitions and fxtransitions at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html. But they work only on pairs of images. ImageMagick -morph does a changing blend between the two images. It does not add any geometric transition, such as wipe for example. Perhaps you could post your 5 JPG images so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @fmw42 the idea is to end up with a basic slideshow comprising of a set of images with a fade transition between each. I will update the question with images when I get home from work.

Comment: `@user2145312` Does my simple command in my answer not do just that for you? It works for me. All delays are equal and the fade is uniform with 9 steps between pairs.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your delay. Perhaps you can explain. But it is not uniform. Many animated gif viewers will not handle delays that change. They works best of a one given delay.

This works fine for me to do a uniform delay using ImageMagick 6.9.10.34 Q16 Mac OSX and viewing it in Safari.

Images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
convert -delay 50 lena.jpg mandril3.jpg zelda1.jpg -morph 9 -loop 0 test.gif
```

[image]

This is what I get from your delay, which starts very slowly and then ends very quickly. Note I put the -set delay right after reading the input and before the -morph. Does that work the way you want in your command?

```
convert lena.jpg mandril3.jpg zelda1.jpg -set delay "%[fx:(t>0&&t<n-1)?10:320]" -morph 9 -loop 0 test2.gif
```

[image]